# Android SQLite Syntax Error exception AndroidHive Tutorial

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax

I have a problem.
I used the sqlite database tutorial from androidhive
(http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

I tried to add a field. But when I do this, i get the following exception:

```
03-26 17:32:37.770: E/SQLiteLog(29021): (1) near "where": syntax error
03-26 17:32:37.770: W/dalvikvm(29021): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416c1e18)
03-26 17:32:37.770: E/AndroidRuntime(29021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 17:32:37.770: E/AndroidRuntime(29021): Process: com.androidhive.androidsqlite, PID: 29021
03-26 17:32:37.770: E/AndroidRuntime(29021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.androidsqlite/com.androidhive.androidsqlite.AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "where": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE vm(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,date TEXT,what TEXT,where TEXT)
03-26 17:32:37.770: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
```

Here is the code:

**AndoidSQLiteTutorialActivity**

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addAppointment(new Appointment("Test date", "Test what", "Test where"));

        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Appointment> appointments = db.getAllAppointments();       

        for (Appointment appointment : appointments) {
            String log = "Id: "+appointment.getID()+" ,What: " + appointment.getWhat() + " ,Where: " + appointment.getWhere();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler**

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appointmentsManager";

    //table name
    private static final String TABLE_VM = "vm";

    //Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_WHAT = "what";
    private static final String KEY_WHERE = "where";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_VM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VM + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_WHAT + " TEXT," + KEY_WHERE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_VM_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VM);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new appointment
    void addAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DATE, appointment.getDate()); 
        values.put(KEY_WHAT, appointment.getWhat());
        values.put(KEY_WHERE, appointment.getWhere()); 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_VM, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single appointment
    Appointment getAppointment(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_VM, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_DATE, KEY_WHAT, KEY_WHERE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        // return contact
        return appointment;
    }

    // Getting All appointments
    public List<Appointment> getAllAppointments() {
        List<Appointment> appointmentList = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VM;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
                appointment.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                appointment.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
                appointment.setWhat(cursor.getString(2));
                appointment.setWhere(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding appintment to list
                appointmentList.add(appointment);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return appointment list
        return appointmentList;
    }

    // Updating single appointment
    public int updateAppointment(Appointment appointment) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DATE, appointment.getDate());
        values.put(KEY_WHAT, appointment.getWhat());
        values.put(KEY_WHERE, appointment.getWhere());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_VM, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(appointment.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single appointment
    public void deleteAppointment(Appointment contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_VM, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting appointments Count
    public int getAppointmentsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_VM;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

**Appointment**

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

public class Appointment {

    //private variables
    int id;
    String date;
    String what;
    String where;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty appointment
     */
    public Appointment(){

    }

    // constructor
    public Appointment(String date, String what, String where){
        this.date = date;
        this.what = what;
        this.where = where;
    }
    // constructor
    public Appointment(int id, String date, String what, String where){
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.what = what;
        this.where = where;
    }

    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this.id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getDate(){
        return this.date;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setDate(String date){
        this.date = date;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getWhat(){
        return this.what;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setWhat(String what){
        this.what = what;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getWhere(){
        return this.where;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setWhere(String where){
        this.where = where;
    }
}
```

Thx for your help.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` is a reserved word in SQLite (as well as all the DB engines which use a SQL-92 compliant language).
It simply can't be used as a column name.

You can replace it with a similar string, like `key_where`, for instance.